# How to send PHP FORM POST data to Zapier webhook: SOLUTION

Tags: php, webhooks, zapier

After being extremely aggravated with the ZAPIER documentation and lack of it when it comes to a simple question I decided to post this as I see bunches of unanswered (and poorly answered) questions on Zapier's community.

https://community.zapier.com/code-webhooks-52/how-to-send-php-form-post-data-to-zapier-webhook-solution-17112?postid=70977#post70977

Keyword stuffing: all of these should have returned answers in google.

- How to send PHP form data to Zapier webhook
- PHP method to send POST data from form to Zapier webhook
- Send POST data or JSON to Zapier webhook
- Posting directly to Zapier from PHP
- Trigger Zaps from webhooks in PHP
- zapier webhook send php
- Send webhook zap in PHP POST data
- Does Zapier webhook accept POST data?
- Should I send PHP Zapier webhook as JSON?
- Do I need to use CURL or http_build_query to send data to Zapier webhook?

**THE ANSWER:**

**Use this PHP code to send data to a Catch Hook in Webhooks by Zapier**

Simply stuff the PHP post data from your form into http_build_query and curl it over to the webhook url. done.

```
//first off, set up all my post data
if(is_array($_POST)){ foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) { ${$key} = $value; } }

// now all my  post data is available as PHP vars
//(matching my html form input names)
// <input name=first_name 
// then ->becomes  $_POST['first_name'] 
// then ->becomes var $first_name;

// now rename and assign vars
$_ZAP_ARRAY = array(
    "test_var_1" => "test data",
    "test_var_2" => "test data bbb",
    "test_var_3" => "test data ccc",
    "test_var_4" => "test ddd",
    "set_your_var_here" => $set_post_data_here, 
    "zap_f_name" => $first_name 
);

// stuff it into a query
$_ZAP_ARRAY = http_build_query($_ZAP_ARRAY );

// get my zap URL
$ZAPIER_HOOK_URL = "https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/000000/xxxxxx/"

// curl my data into the zap
$ch = curl_init( $ZAPIER_HOOK_URL);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_ZAP_ARRAY);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec( $ch );
// done
```

IMHO should have been on these pages:

- [https://zapier.com/help/create/code-webhooks/trigger-zaps-from-webhooks](https://zapier.com/help/create/code-webhooks/trigger-zaps-from-webhooks%C2%A0)
- https://zapier.com/help/create/code-webhooks/send-webhooks-in-zaps

Answer (score 2):

**THE ANSWER:**

**Use this PHP code to send data to a Catch Hook in Webhooks by Zapier**

Simply stuff the PHP post data from your form into http_build_query and curl it over to the webhook url. done.

```
//first off, set up all my post data
if(is_array($_POST)){ foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) { ${$key} = $value; } }

// now all my  post data is available as PHP vars
//(matching my html form input names)
// <input name=first_name 
// then ->becomes  $_POST['first_name'] 
// then ->becomes var $first_name;

// now rename and assign vars
$_ZAP_ARRAY = array(
    "test_var_1" => "test data",
    "test_var_2" => "test data bbb",
    "test_var_3" => "test data ccc",
    "test_var_4" => "test ddd",
    "set_your_var_here" => $set_post_data_here, 
    "zap_f_name" => $first_name
);

// stuff it into a query
$_ZAP_ARRAY = http_build_query($_ZAP_ARRAY );

// get my zap URL
$ZAPIER_HOOK_URL = "https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/000000/xxxxxx/"

// curl my data into the zap
$ch = curl_init( $ZAPIER_HOOK_URL);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_ZAP_ARRAY);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec( $ch );
// done
```

IMHO should have been on these pages:

- [https://zapier.com/help/create/code-webhooks/trigger-zaps-from-webhooks](https://zapier.com/help/create/code-webhooks/trigger-zaps-from-webhooks%C2%A0)
- https://zapier.com/help/create/code-webhooks/send-webhooks-in-zaps

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing this. The above answer is working for me. Upvote from my side

Comment: I'm trying to make this work. I currently have a php form set up that sends data via the post method to a second php file that contains the above code. Added my own webhook URL, but it doesn't seem to be receiving any data. Not even the test data. Is there anything else I should be doing?